# How to ensure product IDs from database are not tampered with

Tags: php, mysql, security, e-commerce

I have this small PHP/MySQL cart system that users add products to, checkout, and pay.
These products all have IDs on them so that when the user checks out,
I can get that product's attributes (price, weight, the vendor's account id, etc).

Right now it would be really easy for someone to open up Firebug,
guess another product ID, change it, and checkout.

What would be the best way to prevent this?
The store and the checkout system are on two different domains if that matters.
I could use something like a unique token
but how would that work if multiple customers could be using the cart at the same time?

**EDIT**: Wow, typed this too fast, left out some important details. The cart is currently represented as JSON that is being stored in a PHP session. All products have an account_id that associates them with a vendor's account.

The problem would occur if a user changed the product id and happened to get a product under another vendor's account (essentially purchasing another company's product from a different company's store) which would be undesirable. Thank you for the answers so far.

Comment: How doe the cart contents get to the checkout?

Comment: Why is it a problem if a user can change the ID - it would be like adding a different item to the cart, wouldn't it? Surely you're storing and calculating prices and quantities internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a server side session to store the cart details.

Every session gets a unique ID, stored in a cookie. All details (selected items, amount, etc) are tied to this sessionId.

By definition, you do not want different customers to use the same cart. Instead, every custommer uses their own separate copy of the cart.

If you need to 'share' the sessionId with some external service, instead calculate a separate unique key and share this key with the third party service (=checkout service in your case).
This ensures that you can uniquely identify your customer in communications with the thirds party, without the third party knowing anything about how you identify or communicate with your customer on your side of the fence. (the important thing to remember is, a sessionId is a shared secret, nobody else should ever know about it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the cart system, the proper way would be to have it duplicate the ID lookup and cost calculations before running the payment. That way, if someone DOES change from a $1.99 box of candy to a $1999.99 HDTV, they will get charged for the tv.

If you don't have access to your cart system, or you can't tell it what the products are and their cost. Get a new cart system.

As a side note: You should NEVER trust data that has come from the user. There should be no need to have to build in trusting the user. Just accept the IDs and run all the numbers on the server.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a hash. When they select a product and the form is rendered, take a hash of the Product Id and store it in a hidden field alongside the Product Id. When the 'checkout' post occurs, take a hash of the Product Id that is posted and compare it to the one that was sent out in the form. If they don't match, then the Product Id has been tampered with. I'm not familiar with PHP so can't provide a code sample but I've used this approach in ASP.NET and it works a charm.

Hope that makes some sense!

Comment: A hash of the product ID could also be tampered with, but use a hash of productID+some other product-specific value that the user doesn't have access to, but the back-end does, and then you have your verification

Comment: Yes you can tamper with the hash, but unless the user can replicate your hashing algorithm, key and salt it still wouldn't match when you re-take the hash on the post back to the server, and you could still tell some tampering had gone on.

Answer (score 0):

And what the threat is? If the client-side has only product IDs, then if they change the ID, they'd be buying different product, and that's all. Or your products are not available for all? If they aren't, you need to use random IDs so that they couldn't be easily guessed.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you have to do is encrypt/decrypt your product id and use it. 
you can use base64_encode() and base64_decode()

Hope this will help

Comment: -1 encrypt != encode. base64 encoding only alters the way the data 'looks', but it is still publicly readable information. And then, encryption is not the solution to this problem.